# Combining photons at a beam splitter and states tensorization

Tags: linear-optics

I wonder what is the operation for 'combining' two polarized photons (one into each input arm, with perfect timing). I would consider three steps:

- 1.The two modes (polarization, arm) should be combined by tensor product (Left x Right states)
- 2.The BS matrix (Theta (R,T), Phi (phase)) should be applied to the previous tensor product
- 3.Symmetry arguments lead me to think that steps (1,2) should also be applied considering left/right inversion of the BS:

  3.1   Apply step 1 with operators in reverse order: Right x Left

  3.2   Apply step 2 with new_Theta = (90º - Theta), R and T are reversed , and new_Phi = - Phi, phase change is opposed.

If this is correct (which I'm pretty unsure) there would be two resulting states, which I would guess are added, in order to represent that the result at each output arm of the BS has a contribution from the two states previously calculated.

Any thoughts about these steps or this operation?

Comment: what do you mean with "combining"? Like, steps to input a pair of photons into a beamsplitter? Or are you asking how to write such a process mathematically?

Comment: Yes, I mean the later:
Is my mathematical description of the tensorization process (which is the modes product and also a two-particle state creation) correct in my post?
BS_mat * (Left X Right) + Symmetric_BS_mat * (Right X Left)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am able to answer my own question.
From the (fantastic) video-lecture by Lakshmi Bala, the beam-splitter operator is like this

[image]

Also, I have come to adapt the result to my own calculations like this:

1- A BS depends on two parameters: Theta, controlling the reflection and trasmission, and Phi, which introduces a phase shift between the reflected and transmited coefficients:
[image]

2 - For two states into the input ports of the BS, the resulting state is the superposition of applying the BS operator (U_bs) to every input state, noticing the complementary relations of Theta and the sign inversion of Phi between the two input ports,  due to the change of components that are reflected and transmited by the BS.
Also, every input must be combined with the other by tensor product, and the U operator must also be tensor-multiplied by itself in order for the states and the operator to have the same dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/10626)